# How to create a Python convolution kernel?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to create a convolution kernel, and the middle is going to be 1.5. Unfortunately I keep running in to ideas on how to do that. I'm trying to create something similar to this

```
Array = [
        [0 , 1 , 0]
        [1 , 1.5 , 1]
        [0 , 1 , 0]
]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since OpenCV uses Numpy to display images, you can simply create a convolution kernel using Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

convolution_kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0], 
                               [1, 1.5, 1], 
                               [0, 1, 0]])
```

Here's the kernel. Note the type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

```
[[0.  1.  0. ]
 [1.  1.5 1. ]
 [0.  1.  0. ]]
```

To convolve a kernel with an image, you can use [`cv2.filter2D()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#d-convolution-image-filtering). Something like this

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
result = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, convolution_kernel)
```

---

For more information about kernel construction, look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)). Here are some common kernels and the result after convolving. Using this input image:

[image]

**Sharpen kernel**

```
sharpen = np.array([[0, -1, 0], 
                    [-1, 5, -1], 
                    [0, -1, 0]])
```

[image]

**Laplacian kernel**

```
laplacian = np.array([[0, 1, 0], 
                      [1, -4, 1], 
                      [0, 1, 0]])
```

[image]

**Emboss kernel**

```
emboss = np.array([[-2, -1, 0], 
                   [-1, 1, 1], 
                   [0, 1, 2]])
```

[image]

**Outline kernel**

```
outline = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], 
                    [-1, 8, -1], 
                    [-1, -1, -1]])
```

[image]

**Bottom sobel**

```
bottom_sobel = np.array([[-1, -2, -1], 
                         [0, 0, 0], 
                         [1, 2, 1]])
```

[image]

**Left sobel**

```
left_sobel = np.array([[1, 0, -1], 
                       [2, 0, -2], 
                       [1, 0, -1]])
```

[image]

**Right sobel**

```
right_sobel = np.array([[-1, 0, 1], 
                        [-2, 0, 2], 
                        [-1, 0, 1]])
```

[image]

**Top sobel**

```
top_sobel = np.array([[1, 2, 1], 
                      [0, 0, 0], 
                      [-1, -2, -1]])
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I was way too vague on my question. The size of the array is going to vary, so it can be whatever size the argument is, it's going to create a NxN array, and it has to have 1.5 in the middle then.

Comment: Depending on what you want the rest of the kernel to contain, you could do `a = np.ones((N, N)); a[N//2, N//2] = 1.5`. Also check out [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) and [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html).

Comment: I find this answer both helpful and enlightening, thank you for taking the time to post it so nicely!