# Image-processing convolution kernels are calculated dynamically

Tags: python, numpy

Using standard `numpy` and `cv2.filter2D` solutions I can apply static convolutions to an image:

> [image]
>
> ```py
> import numpy as np
>
> convolution_kernel = np.array([[-2, -1, 0], 
>                                [-1, 1, 1], 
>                                [0, 1, 2]])
>
> import cv2
>
> image = cv2.imread('1.png') result = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, convolution_kernel)
> ```
>
> [image]

*(example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58383803/3310334)*

Every pixel at `[i, j]` in the output image has a value calculated by centering a 3x3 "window" onto `[i, j]` in the input image, and then multiplying each value in the window by the corresponding value in the convolution kernel (Hadamard product) and finally summing the 9 products to get the value for `[i, j]` in the output image (for each color channel).

[image]

*(image from: https://github.com/ashushekar/image-convolution-from-scratch#convolution)*

In my case, the function to perform to calculate for each output pixel is not as simple as sum of Hadamard product. It is for each pixel calculated from operations performed on known-size windows into two input matrices centered around that pixel.

I have two input matrixes ("images"), like

```py
A = [[179,  97,  77, 118, 144, 105],
     [ 68,  56, 184, 210, 141, 230],
     [178, 166, 218,  47, 106, 172],
     [ 38, 183,  50, 185,  48,  87],
     [ 60, 200, 228, 232,   6, 190],
     [253,  75, 231, 166, 117, 134]]

B = [[116,  95,  94, 220,  80, 223],
     [135,   9, 166,  78,   5, 129],
     [102, 167, 120,  81, 141,  29],
     [ 83, 117,  81, 129, 255,  48],
     [130, 231, 165,   7, 187, 169],
     [ 44, 137,  16,  50, 229, 202]]
```

And in the output matrix, each `[i, j]` pixel should be calculated as the sum of all of `A[u,v] ** 2 - B[u,v] ** 2` values for `[u, v]` coordinates within 3x3 "windows" onto the two (same-sized) input matrixes.

How can I calculate this output matrix quickly in Python?

Using numpy, it seems to be the 3x3 sums of `A * A - B * B`, but how to do those sums? Or is there another "2d map" process I could be using?

I've written a loop-based solution to calculate the expected output for these two examples:

```py
W = 3 # size of kernel is WxW
out = np.zeros(A.shape)
difference_of_squares = A * A - B * B
for i, j in np.ndindex(out.shape):
    starti = max(i - W//2, 0) # use smaller kernels at input's boundaries, output will have same dimension as input
    stopi = min(i - W//2 + W, np.shape(out)[0]) # I'm not worried at this point about what happens at boundaries
    startj = max(j - W//2, 0) # standard convolution solutions are often just reducing output size or padding input with zeroes
    stopj = min(j - W//2 + W, np.shape(out)[1])
    out[i, j] = np.sum(difference_of_squares[starti:stopi, startj:stopj])
print(out)
```

```
[[   8423.   11816.   10372.   41125.   35287.   31747.]
 [  29370.   65887.   38811.   61252.   51033.   51845.]
 [  24756.   60119.  109133.   35101.   70005.   18757.]
 [   8641.   62463.  126935.   14530.    2255.  -64752.]
 [  36623.  110426.  163513.   33812.  -50035. -146450.]
 [  22268.  100132.  130190.   83010.  -10163.  -88994.]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html):

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# Same shape as original (6x6)
>>> convolve2d(A**2-B**2, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int), mode='same')
array([[   8423,   11816,   10372,   41125,   35287,   31747],
       [  29370,   65887,   38811,   61252,   51033,   51845],
       [  24756,   60119,  109133,   35101,   70005,   18757],
       [   8641,   62463,  126935,   14530,    2255,  -64752],
       [  36623,  110426,  163513,   33812,  -50035, -146450],
       [  22268,  100132,  130190,   83010,  -10163,  -88994]])

# Shape reduce by 1 (5x5)
>>> convolve2d(A**2-B**2, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int), mode='valid')
array([[ 65887,  38811,  61252,  51033],
       [ 60119, 109133,  35101,  70005],
       [ 62463, 126935,  14530,   2255],
       [110426, 163513,  33812, -50035]])
```

**Note**: You have to play around with the "mode" and "limit" parameters until you get what you want.

**Update**

If the border is not a problem at this point, you can use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

>>> np.sum(sliding_window_view(A**2-B**2, (3, 3)), axis=(2, 3))
array([[ 65887,  38811,  61252,  51033],
       [ 60119, 109133,  35101,  70005],
       [ 62463, 126935,  14530,   2255],
       [110426, 163513,  33812, -50035]])
```

Comment: You have a (6, 6) image, After sliding you have a (4, 4, 3, 3) => 4x4 for the image without padding and 3x3 for your conv kernel. You have to sum on kernel dimensions (axis 2 and 3) to restore the original dimension (without the padding)? Does it clear (I can't do better in english :-P)?

Comment: @theonlygusti. I updated my answer. In fact, it works perfectly fine with convolve2d. I think I modified the value of A[1,0] when you posted your first comment.